# How to know what firmware a new Nexus 4 has?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, firmware, nexus-4

I would like to buy a new Nexus 4 to flash the Ubuntu phone on it.

It's written what firmware (Nexus 4 mako occam) the phone should have, but how to find out if I buy it from the store?

Answer (score 0):

As you can **replace** the Nexus 4 firmware, per the instructions for recovery, this is not really relevant.

See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install >> **Device factory reset**

---

For the **Nexus 4**, Android **4.2.2** (JDQ39), **4.3** (JWR66Y), and **4.4** 'KitKat' (KRT16S) are available.

See: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam